# How to organize packages in gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

A GWT project has three packages client, server and shared? Can anyone tell which all classes are organized in each package? And what is the need of shared package?
I'm beginner in GWT. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

First, have a look at [the GWT explanation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects) regarding project layout.

In short: the `client` package and its subpackages contain the classes that will be compiled to JavaScript and executed on the client. For these classes, certain [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility) apply.

The `server` package contains the code that is executed on the server side. For the `shared` package: you don'n necessarily need it, but it possibly would make sense to put the classes there that are getting transfered from client to server through [GWTs' client-server-communication mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to pass the following tutorial and work with MVP pattern that clears a lot questions how to organize your project:
[mvp pattern](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture)

To clear you question:

- Client: Every Code will be compiled into JavaScript and running on Client
- Server: Code won't be compiled into JavaScript and runnning on Server
- Shared: Code can run on Client or Server. Code will be compiled into JavaScript.

You don't need a Shared Package you could pack all client-classes in the client-package, but if you have classes, which are used on both sides, its better for understanding.

Comment: Your link goes to MVP, not MVC :)

Comment: You might mention that Shared is where your Pojo DTO Business Rules type classes go, so the client and server can easily share the same business objects.

Comment: Thanks Kenoyer130, thats also a good point. You can also share Proxyclasses or Requestfactories in the shared folder. So i didn't wanted to specify for one propose.